# What is wrong with my classpath for JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, classpath

I cant help myself but to finally ask here... I am using Windows 8.1 and I always need to copy the JUnit.jar files to my active projects, because whatever I try its not working. At the moment my classpath is set to:

`C:\Program Files\junit\junit.jar;C:\Program Files\junit\junit-4.4.jar;C:\Program Files\junit\junit-4.11.jar`

JUNIT_HOME is set to `C:\Program Files\junit`

Whenever I try to run a test using eg.: `java junit-4.4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyMatrixTest`

I get the following error saying main class junit-4.4.jar not found. I also tried using only one version of junit in my classpath (even if it would be good to have all of them included, since I often need to run tests from different versions), but it didnt make a change.. I just dont know what to try to make it working..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to specify the `-cp` option.

Comment: But wouldnt this overwrite my classpath variable set in windows? I then get the error: main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore not found

So I am speaking here of a classpath set as a systemvariable in Windows... This usually should be taken as default without using -cp or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `CLASSPATH` environment variable set correctly, then you need to execute

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

without the reference to the `.jar` file.

The [`java` application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) has the following usage

```
java [ options ] class [ arguments ]
```

If you aren't going to specify any options, then the first argument needs to be the class name. In this case, that is `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`.

Comment: Ahhh thanks that is exactly what I was looking for! Now where you say it it is pretty obvious, that I dont have to name the package, since it is already in my classpath! This working fine now! Thanks again!

One more question is left: How does the application launcher knows which version of junit I want to launch, since all v4 versions have the same "architecture".

I am even more surprised by the fact that my example was run with JUnit 3.8, whereby the class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore doesnt exist in the package of v3.8 o.O

Comment: @user The `java` launcher doesn't know about library versions. It only knows about `.class` files. When you add a classpath entry, java has access to the classes contained in that entry. If you have multiple classes with same name, you may have a jar hell (check that out). As for the junit version, was the v4 jar in your working directory? The working directory ia added to the classpath automatically

Comment: For now I have three different JUnit versions in my classpath: junit.jar (v3.8) junit-4.4.jar and junit-4.11.jar. The junit version 3.8 has a different architecure than the junit 4 versions, so there shouldnt be any complications. The testrunners were divided into different classes that time and a JUnitCore class was not existing. To my surprise the tests were run anyways with JUnit v 3.8 using the following: java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyTestClass. But I double checked now and in the archive there is no such class... But maybe I should rethink about having all versions in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\junit\junit-4.4.jar";. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyMatrixTest
```

Comment: I know this (or as said I can even copy the junit.jar to my folder), but still my classpath is not working as it should.. Because if it is working properly I shouldnt name a directory at all, should I?

But yes this is working.. Is there no way to make it shorter?

Comment: What's your purpose of doing so, if I may? Because usually, the path is specified that way or using `java -cp /path/to/all/jars/* your.java.Application`

Comment: I have a lot of different smaller tasks for university. And each of them includes JUnit tests, which I want to run. I was just looking for a way to easily run them without even copying my jars always to the directory or always typing that long path. Thats why I also set my path variable just for not always typing the path of my JDK.. Only a matter of laziness I guess! Thanks for your help anyways!